# Flowtype - encode a type refinement in another type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In Flow, with a [disjoint union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) type I can use [type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) to selectively target a subset of the union based on a certain property.

That's great, if I want to put all my code in a one switch statement. If I want to split my code up into functions, however, I don't know how to 'encode' the type refinement into a type declaration so that flow carries on 'knowing' that the refinement has taken place in those functions.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do - it's available on the flow playground [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwAqAFgJYB2A5mALxiphgA+YA3mFngFxgDkAhjwA0YPtwCMYAL70mrdjlzd+QkdwBMUmczYdFvAEYr93AMyaG2+VwNHuAFnOydCpQGMVr7gFZHl3W49uADZNVCgAVzJXdBI4MjBsACdydGJyKgAKdFJKbjTKAEpuADc4EgATVhkAZwQSdFciMCycigA6XQKqhgZXPmr8ZW5XOOq4GFw2+AoW9La+AoBuMH1E3D4Aa0WZBmBgMCg+Ehhq4T6yHnQV-D4wVwOSXBhKkigrfBJqmx27-sHDYajcaTaazShtVxLFZrTbbHpgPYHI4nM58C5XfQ3eK3B5PF5vXRgT68dw-PoDEk8QFkMYTKZwGbZOYLZardZbGTSaSoJIpfIzZzWZTCURgCSSAo-VCIhBEPhXQnlOBgACSYAoJGK+CZlAA8lACAoAIJgMbsOVXWCIMBrKDkXBffnS-boZVxGCYc34ODYGKjMB1bLvXgCYQwEgbD7xbL4cmDATcaroeW4AC2uDI6AA-M7nWBJu0wAAJHBwGMxPowU2YTN8AAe3DBFH1hrwRryrXzdfQGfKX0FemUUklezCkWisXivMz-JbxuaOubBuNHfSXRYMkRTK+xLtZBuXz4MCrcq1IneMhGNOB9JmlxcvDAAGpzek522OgpJbt9kRredXy+HgNjIRAeHNeVVR4M9sH6AZKluRcwDgAkFBDHhN32M1skg+owCVB10SRY4c16IE6VBfglGfV89WXD8FlQaQgA).

Is there a (non-manual, non-redundant) way to declare a subtype of `Thing`, or some other syntax, to encode the type refinement so that I can 'pass it on' into the `printThingOfTypeA` function?

```
type Thing = 
  | { type: 'a', a: 1 }
  | { type: 'a', a: 2 }
  | { type: 'b', b: 3 }
  | { type: 'b', b: 4 }
  | { type: 'c', c: 5 }
  | { type: 'c', c: 6 }

function printThing (thing: Thing): void {
  switch (thing.type) {
    case 'a': console.log(thing.a); break;
    // fails, can't be a c field if type is 'b'
    case 'b': console.log(thing.c); break;
    // fails, can't be an a field if type is 'c'
    case 'c': console.log(thing.a); break;
  }
}

printThing({ type: 'a', a: 1 })

// what type do I give thingOfTypeA so that flow refines Thing
// to only the options with type 'a', like in the case 'a': statement?
//
// e.g. Hypothetical syntax: (thingOfTypeA: Thing extends { type: 'a' })
//
function printThingOfTypeA (thingOfTypeA: Thing) {
  // this is fine as all have a type
  console.log('type: ' + thingOfTypeA.type)
  // how can this 'know' that I've passed a thing of type 'a'
  // so that it doesn't fail?
  console.log('a: ' + thingOfTypeA.a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered splitting apart the type of `Thing` into three definitions?

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4FwTwBwU2AVAFgSwHYHMCCwC8AoUUAH2AG9xoYAuYAcgENaAaYemgRmAF8DDgTykWDQbNWNAEzc8eAJBC4SNOgBCuXoQEVhdAEZjdNAMzS+-Mtup6DNACzS5ChCgwBhdWa0KRAYzE+aAFZTPi9KX38aADYHQiclDFxgDWJnZUwUkBIE1UzzHNcZQigAJzQwHIAKQXC6RhY2YE4uAEoi0AB6DuAAd0R6MEtgABMAe2AASWB0ZAA3ODAXdAB5ADN4SmwAZ3HFgeBVgBtRnuASmFW0GC20jBSu8HHR1EOIcEQ4UagwZGebnuQiyGohYh2QAGs4Gh3nAfPQtnBRDQtmABjAALYwVBgAD89w6+OAMAAdOhicAABLQUaLGA-OGHYBbCDY+gADxolUWyjWG1gmBoOSJbLAWOGNxqOlE3DahC6KVWAFdUD4fs9gKVyjleZsuUsdfzBUtMC0yHkHtybsgbpdUHB4axDoz+vNWJY8j4-qNDiTjuhKrRvHRgABqd489abYkKWV8B6IE7AOGocM3Wjg1AnWjvfYTWiuqDwhHDN3cxKjVbAxjm7o7HODQEjUbXVCBg70ZCHPFmT2oHY+4l+gONbNhssrSP84n0WMgLhAA))

```
type ThingA =
  | { type: 'a', a: 1 }
  | { type: 'a', a: 2 }

type ThingB =
  | { type: 'b', b: 3 }
  | { type: 'b', b: 4 }

type ThingC =
  | { type: 'c', c: 5 }
  | { type: 'c', c: 6 }

type Thing = 
  | ThingA
  | ThingB
  | ThingC

printThing({ type: 'a', a: 1 })

// what type do I give thingOfTypeA so that flow refines Thing
// to only the options with type 'a', like in the case 'a': statement?
//
// e.g. Hypothetical syntax: (thingOfTypeA: Thing extends { type: 'a' })
//
function printThingOfTypeA(thingOfTypeA: ThingA) {
  // this is fine as all have a type
  console.log('type: ' + thingOfTypeA.type)
  // how can this 'know' that I've passed a thing of type 'a'
  // so that it doesn't fail?
  console.log('a: ' + thingOfTypeA.a)
}
```

That way your function can accept the more specific `ThingA`, while other code can use the more general `Thing`.

Alternatively , if you can't break it apart, you can just write a type describing what you need in the function param, but then you can't pass *any* `Thing` into it, since that thing might not have the requisite properties:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4FwTwBwU2AVAFgSwHYHNgF5gChSgA+wA3uNDAFzADkAhjQDTB3UCMwAvvgcMWZFjV6TFtQBMXPLz6lyQ2gCNRi6gGYuPAv3lUlK6gBZNMnYL00AxqMvUArCd5mKw681vAAbJq3BLAe1QAZzAWDhwSc2EGZlZgcW4CAODQunFqJDRMCKjaGLFgNm5fADMAV1RLMGRA4CgAJzQwTIwAeRL4CgBBAAowFDaO7upIlzzRONQygFtFGHrOAEpSXxBkoP8AGxgAOk3-dB6aXJpgAGpwAfR2ztgunfNF1b9Aje29g6O404v+rJvujs6E8CMUCA0mi1rkM7j06GwQaAIahmlcAbC0ssAPRY4AAUXq9X89VwQA))

```
type Thing = 
  | { type: 'a', a: 1 }
  | { type: 'a', a: 2 } 
  | { type: 'b', b: 3 }
  | { type: 'b', b: 4 }
  | { type: 'c', c: 5 }
  | { type: 'c', c: 6 }

const a1 = {type: 'a', a: 2}
const a2: Thing = {type: 'a', a: 1}

function printThingOfTypeA(thingOfTypeA: {type: 'a', a: number}) {
  console.log('type: ' + thingOfTypeA.type)
  console.log('a: ' + thingOfTypeA.a)
}

printThingOfTypeA(a1)
printThingOfTypeA(a2) // Error
```

Comment: This will work ok for the simple case like in the example, but unfortunately it breaks down if I have more than 1 type of field I want to categorise on in different scenarios. Also, in any case I want to be able to do this 'on the fly' without having to deeply embed it into the structure of the type.

Comment: Added a small "alternative" section to my answer. I think what you're doing might be difficult to statically type check. It would be easier to answer your question (or know if it's not possible) if you included a full example of what you need.